# Angular2: Get async objectID and pass it

Tags: angular, asynchronous

When displaying a childview, which expects an ID, like this:

```
<app-customerview [customerID]="assignedCustomer"></app-customerview>
```

it works like expected, but when I try to pass it directly:

```
<app-customerview [customerID]="currentTask.customerId"></app-customerview>
```

[image: Error: currentTask.customerId]

or when using the safe access operator:

```
<app-customerview [customerID]="currentTask?.customerId"></app-customerview>
```

[image]

I think the problem might be how the data is retrieved (async), but I'm not really sure and don't understand why the second option is invalid (because `currentTask` isn't actually undefined).

Retrieving the data:

```
getCurrentTask() {
   this._tasksService.getTaskById(this.currentTaskId).subscribe(
      (toReturnTask: Task) => {
         this.currentTask = toReturnTask;
         this.assignedCustomer = "" + this.currentTask.customerId;
       }
   );
}
```

[The child](https://pastebin.com/cM69hBbb) `<app-customerview>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, this is asynchronous. So when child is rendered, `currentTask.customerId` is not set. That can be solved with the safe navigation operator like suggested by **n00dl3**.

Okay, well, that doesn't solve the following issue, in your child you have a function that depends on `customerID` and it's fired `OnInit`, so at that point `customerID` will not have a value. So remove the function `getCurrentCustomer` from `ngOnInit`.

**UPDATE: USING SUBJECT:**

You could utilize a shared service like explained in the [**Official docs**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service). But we can also do this without that, like so:

import `Subject`:

```ts
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

Declare `Subject` in your child:

```ts
public static fireFunction: Subject<string> = new Subject(); // name however you like
```

In child constructor subscribe whenever the value is emitted and fire your function then:

```ts
CustomerviewComponent.fireFunction.subscribe(res => {
  // apparently the input doesn't have time to be set, therefore passed the value with observable
  // console.log('cont: ', this.content) // will be undefined
  this.getCurrentCustomer(res) // call function with parameter customerID (res)
})
```

When you have assigned the value in your parent, you can emit this value to child, which then fires the `getCurrentCustomer`:

```ts
getCurrentTask() {
   this._tasksService.getTaskById(this.currentTaskId).subscribe(
      (toReturnTask: Task) => {
         this.currentTask = toReturnTask;
         CustomerviewComponent.fireFunction.next(this.currentTask.customerId); // emit to child
       }
   );
}
```

This means that it's not neccessary to have

```ts
[customerID]="currentTask?.customerId"
```

..in your child tag, unless you need it. This value will be set after "some time". You could remove that from tag, and instead assign the Observable to the local variable in your child.

### [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GsIYOb4V3DCME0OkjekG?p=preview)

(with `Subject` and `ViewChild` examples, check console as well)

---

**ORIGINAL POST USING VIEWCHILD:**

One solution is to use `ViewChild` and fire the function from the parent, once `currentTask.customerId` is set. That way we can make sure the child component has `customerID` set.

So import....

```ts
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
```

declare in your parent:

```ts
@ViewChild(CustomerviewComponent) customerviewComp: CustomerviewComponent
```

Now you can fire functions in your child from the parent, call `getCurrentCustomer` after you have populated `currentTask`:

```ts
getCurrentTaskAndSpikeeId() {
   this._tasksService.getTaskById(this.currentTaskId).subscribe(
      (toReturnTask: Task) => {
         this.currentTask = toReturnTask;
         this.customerviewComp.getCurrentCustomer(); // here
       }
   );
}
```

and as said, use the safe navigation operator in the template:

```ts
<app-customerview [customerID]="currentTask?.customerId"></app-customerview>
```

Comment: Seems like a good solution to the problem. The reason then, that passing the `assignedCustomer` works, is because it is done before executing the childs `OnInit`?

Comment: @WouterVanherck Well, since `assignedCustomer` does not have a property, Angular can handle it being null, check this, where `{{title}}` doesn't throw error: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator . You are also very lucky in that sense if the `assignedCustomer` actually is being set in time before `ngOnInit` is fired. Usually the async value is received later, so that `OnInit` in child would fire before `assignedCustomer` has a value.

Comment: So, I should always let my parent activate the child-function? Just in case if my luck runs out?

Comment: Just to mention (if you are considering option): `ngOnChanges` can be used also to capture changes, but that would not be a good solution at all, since upon initialization this would be fired before value is set. Maybe using Observables would be good here, parent emits after receiving value and child subscribes to and then fires the `getCurrentCustomer`. That, or use viewChild :)

Comment: Since I'm fairly new to Angular, I'm going to try the viewChild option (because you've already written an example).

Comment: Okay, I could add a simple Observable example later in my answer as well when I have a little more time. I'll let you know. Until then, happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

`currentTask` is undefined while the asynchronous call hasn't finished, you should use the safe access operator in your template: `{{foo?.bar}}` :

```
<app-customerview [customerID]="currentTask?.customerId"></app-customerview>
```

Comment: Then that does not come from that part but from your `app-customerview` component... (I guess you are trying to access an `outlet` property of an object that  does not exist either in that component).

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the term `outlet` but I checked the childview (`app-customerview`) and I don't see any uses without the safe access operator.

Comment: I can't tell you because my crystal ball is broken, so I cannot read your code right now... :-D Maybe that does not come from the template, maybe from the typescript, please provide the code from that component...

Comment: Welp, I didn't think the problem would be deeper than the parent component but here's the child if you would like to take a look https://pastebin.com/cM69hBbb

Comment: just add `*ngIf="currentTask"`

Comment: does not seem to come from the child @WouterVanherck

Comment: @Ivaro18 The `<customerview>` can be loaded from more than one place. Is it still a good solution to include every possible parent in the `*ngIf`?

Comment: nope, you should listen for changes of `customerID` instead of just using it in `ngOnInit` of `CustomerviewComponent`

Answer (score 0):

Besides `@ViewChild` and `rxjs/Subject` like **AJT_82** mentioned in his answer, there's another way to do this. There's a function that listens for changes which you can import in your child:

```
import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes['customerId']) {
            this.getCurrentCustomer()();
        }
        console.log(changes);
    }
```

The passed id

```
<app-customerview [customerID]="currentTask?.customerId"></app-customerview>
```